# Getting single value from the N dim histogram in NumPy or SciPy

Tags: numpy, scipy

Assume I have a data like this:

`x = np.random.randn(4, 100000)`
and I fit a histogram
`hist = np.histogramdd(x, density=True)`
What I want is to get the probability of number `g`, e.g. `g=0.1`. Assume some hypothetical function `foo` then.

```
g = 0.1
prob = foo(hist, g)
print(prob)
>> 0.2223124214
```

How could I do something like this, where I get probability back for a single or a vector of numbers for a fitted histogram? Especially histogram that is N-dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

histogramdd takes `O(r^D)` memory, and unless you have a very large dataset or very small dimension you will have a poor estimate. Consider your example data, 100k points in 4-D space, the default histogram will be `10 x 10 x 10 x 10`, so it will have 10k bins.

```py
x = np.random.randn(4, 100000)
hist = np.histogramdd(x.transpose(), density=True)
np.mean(hist[0] == 0)
```

gives something arround `0.77` meaning that `77%` of the bins in the histogram have no points.

You probably want to smooth the distribution. Unless you have a good reason to not do, I would suggest you to use [Gaussian kernel-density Estimate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html#scipy-stats-gaussian-kde)

```py
x = np.random.randn(4, 100000) # d x n array
f = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(x) # d-dimensional PDF
f([1,2,3,4]) # evaluate the PDF in a given point
```